# API for Tivoli Workload Scheduler (TWS)

Tags: .net, bash, ssh, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

Is there an API for IBM TWS? The closest I have found is some sort of settings file or fat xml strings to send to *something*.

I would prefer something Dotnet and Rest but beggars can't be choosers.

(my google fu isn't that bad but IBM docs seem to elude me)

**Update**

I have something I believe is a working solution. I use Dotnet SSH to the server and run Bash scripts there. SSH on Dotnet is not mature and Bash is stringy. It is not the best of solutions but, at least for now, solves my problems.

Answer (score 3):

I've just seen this old post without an answer, in case this is still needed...

Since IBM Workload Scheduler (distributed) 9.3 FP2, the product expose full REST APIs. They are the same API internally used by the UI and that covers every Model and Plan action.

On z/OS and previous versions (since 8.3) there are full J2EE APIs, also in this case internally used by the UI and that covers every Model and Plan action.
In addition there is a limited set of xml based web services.
And of course command lines to be used in scripts.

The Integration Workbench provided with the product contains sample and documentation to use the APIs.

The documentation of both Java APIs and web services is also available in the IBM Knowledge Center [Developer's Guide: Driving IBM Workload Automation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGSPN_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/common/src_dgd/awsddmst_welcome.html)

Available Rest APIs are documented online with a Swagger UI at https://start.wa.ibmserviceengage.com/twsd/ or on any 9.4 master at the URL `https://<master_hostname>:<https_port>/twsd/`

Comment: https://start.wa.ibmserviceengage.com/twsd/ asks for username and password, are there any demo values for this available to test?

Comment: Nope, they cannot be executed on the sandbox.
To try the APIs you have to use an on-prem server, or sign for a SaaS trial (https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/workload-automation). You will have Swagger doc under <hostname:port>/twsd

Answer (score 1):

TWS has an API. You should be able to access it in the url: `https://<master_hostname>:<https_port>/twsd/`. It follows the [Swagger standard](https://swagger.io/)

There is a documentation online in this url: https://start.wa.ibmserviceengage.com/twsd/ but if you try to access it directly, you'll get an Access Denied error. To fix it, try to go to https://ibmserviceengage.com accept the fearmongering messages and try to access the first documentation link again.

There is a [useful API samples repository](https://github.com/WorkloadAutomation/TWS_REST_API_samples) with code that will help you to access the API. In the Python sample there is a [wacoon.ini](https://github.com/WorkloadAutomation/TWS_REST_API_Python_samples/blob/master/python/waconn.ini) that you must edit with your server and username.